# How to use redirect object in Next JS new app directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Hi i'm trying to write a project that written with normal Next JS 13. But i am trying to do this with new experimental app directory. So there is no getServerSideProps and when i try to return redirect object it doesnt work. I also tried it with new data Fetching functions

my page.tsx

```
'use client'
// ...imports...
async function controlSession(context: NextPageContext) {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  if(!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/auth",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return session;
}

export default function Home(context: NextPageContext) {
  controlSession(context)

  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="text-2xl text-green-500">Netflix Clone</h1>
      <button
        className="p-2 px-4 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 text-white"
        onClick={() => signOut()}
      >
        Sign Out
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

The original function

[image: nextjs code]

Comment: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/redirect